# How do I find the number of consonants,and vowels separately in a given sentence

Tags: c

How can I add on to the existing program below? I need to be able to find the number of consonants,words,spaces,and special characters. I already have the vowels?

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CountVowels
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the String:");
        String text = bf.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of vowels in the given sentence are " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? It seems straightforward to modify your current code.

Comment: Btw, `y` can be either a vowel or a consonant sound. Compare `Gypsy` with `yacht` and `May`. It can be both: `tyre` (British spelling of `tire`). Ditto with `i`. And with `u`: `quarter`. There's a difference between a vowel letter and a vowel sound.

Comment: Asking the same thing again and again isn't appreciated.  I'm voting to close this and every other duplicate you've littered this forum with.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to write your code for you, but give a few ideas.

1. **Consonants.** You already count the number of vowels. By definition, everything that is not a vowel is a consonant. (Excluding whitespace and punctuation, of course.) Or, of course, you could count them just like you count vowels, by listing exactly the letters to match against.
2. **Words and spaces**. If you know the number of spaces, you know the number of words. There is a space between every two words, so the number of words is the number of spaces, plus one.
3. **Special characters**. If a letter is not a consonant or a vowel or a space, it's something else -- in this case, I assume a "special character." So if you add up all the vowels, consonants, and spaces, and subtract that number from the total length of your input, you'll have the number of special characters.

Furthermore, in the code posted above you only check for lowercase vowels. This is fine, but first you'll want to convert your input string to lowercase like so: `text.toLowerCase()`.

You may want to consider writing a series of methods like so:

```
private boolean isConsonant(char x) { ... }
private boolean isVowel(char x) { ... }
private boolean isWhitespace(char x) { ... }
```

Then when you iterate through the characters of your input string, you can simplify your is-this-a-[something]? checks.

Finally, you'll want to keep separate counters for your different "types." So instead of just `int count`, you'll probably want `int vowelCount`, `int consonantCount`, and `int spaceCount`.